# Video.js get auto poster onDomready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

i have javascript code to get the HTML5 video thumbnail, i can get the video thumbnail while click the button, i want to get this thumbnail onDomready with the currentTime attribute that i need the thumbnail of the video by some amount of time like 10sec, 20sec and or 1st sec of the video

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
    "use strict";

    var video, $output;
    var scale = 0.25;

    var initialize = function() {
        $output = $("#output");
        video = $("#video").get(0);
        $("#capture").click(captureImage);                
    };

    var captureImage = function() {

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth * scale;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight * scale;
        canvas.getContext('2d')
              .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $output.prepend(img);
    };

    $(initialize);            

}());
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls">
    <source src="uploads/post_videos/4d2fba78d9fcd7f59567e459c9b65404_131902_popcorntest.mp4" />
</video>

<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```